# Stored Procedure not updating when Fetch Status = -1

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a sp that will find a match based on certain fields of Table1 from Table2. If it finds a match then it updates a field to Match. If not then it will update the field to blank. Basically it works when there is Match but it won't work if there isn't.

```
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1)
BEGIN
    Update Table1 Set Field2='' Where Field1 = @Field1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Table1_cursor INTO @Field1
END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    Update Table1 Set Field2='Match' Where Field1 = @Field1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Table1_cursor INTO @Field1
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could quite possibly be bettered solved using a set operation, joining table1 and table2 and conditionally setting the field in table1 with a case statement.

```
update t1
set
    field2 = case when t2.field1 is not null then 'match' else '' end
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.field1 = t2.field1
```